# Get Height of binary search tree recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I've been trying make a function to get the height of a binary tree in recursive way.

```
int BSNode::getHeight() const //Returns the height of the tree.
{
    if (this->_left == nullptr && this->_right == nullptr)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return std::max(this->_left->getHeight(), this->_right->getHeight()) + 1;
    }
}
```

I debugged my code and for some reason, I got access violation error on the 'if condition' line. I can't see why I'm still getting this error. I'm suppose that it happening because one of my left or right is null, but I cant see other way to make it.
This is my function for inserting a node to the tree:

```
void BSNode::insert(string value) //Inserts node to the tree.
{
    if (value > this->_data)
    {
        if (this->_right != NULL)
        {
            this->_right->insert(value);
        }
        else
        {
            this->_right = new BSNode(value);
        }
    }
    else if (value < this->_data)
    {
        if (this->_left != NULL)
        {
            this->_left->insert(value);
        }
        else
        {
            this->_left = new BSNode(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class I built:

```
class BSNode
{
    private:
        string _data;
        BSNode* _left;
        BSNode* _right;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. Always use a debugger before you ask .

Comment: Suppose only one of `left` and `right` is null?

Comment: ***I debugged my code and for some reason, I got access violation error.*** If you have Visual Studio when it hits an access violation walk up the callstack to your code to see the line of your code that caused the access violation. I expect gdb will do the same.

Comment: @drescherjm I fixed the post. The line is the if condition.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use `this->` syntax when accessing members; only use if the member has the same name as the parameter (in that case, rename the parameter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The negation of the condition in this if statement

```
if (this->_left == nullptr && this->_right == nullptr)
```

is

```
else if ( not ( this->_left == nullptr && this->_right == nullptr) )
```

that is in turn equivalent to

```
else if ( this->_left != nullptr || this->_right != nullptr )
```

However in the function there is ignored the fact that either `this->_left` or `this->_right` can be equal to nullptr.

```
    return std::max(this->_left->getHeight(), this->_right->getHeight()) + 1;
```

Also it is unclear why the height has the signed type `int` instead of some unsigned type as for example `size_t`.

I suppose that the head of the tree is always unequal to `nullptr`. Otherwise you should rewrite the function as a static member function with one parameter: pointer to the head node.

The function can look the following way

```
size_t BSNode::getHeight() const //Returns the height of the tree.
{
        return  1 + std::max(
                this->_left  == nullptr ? 0 : this->_left->getHeight(), 
                this->_right == nullptr ? 0 : this->_right->getHeight());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand where I was wrong. Fixed my code.

Comment: @drescherjm I accepted.